# Sending multiple messages to a server using Java Websockets Client side?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websocket, client, tyrus

```
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) {

session.getBasicRemote.sendText("Echo me");

session.addMessageHandler(new MessageHandler.Whole<String>() {

            public void onMessage(String arg0) {
                System.out.println(arg0);
            }
        });
}
```

I send a message, and it's echoed back to me. Well what if I wanted to send another message? 
How would I do that?

The reason I ask is because I'm logging in to a server, and they send me back a message stating if I'm successfully logged in or not.

After I've been successfully logged in, I want to send another message querying the server about different information I require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WebSocketContainer.connectToServer(...)](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.6/javax/websocket/WebSocketContainer.html#connectToServer(java.lang.Class,%20java.net.URI)) method returns Session object. When client is connected, you can use this to send messages (see [Session.getBasicRemote().sendText(...)](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.6/javax/websocket/RemoteEndpoint.Basic.html#sendText(java.lang.String)) or [Session.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(...)](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.6/javax/websocket/RemoteEndpoint.Basic.html#sendBinary(java.nio.ByteBuffer))).